# Issue with generics in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I have a problem while adding a new class in my existing structure. I am going to explain my problem as much clear as i can

```
public interface Imust
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string File { get; set; }
    string RowKey { get; set; }
    string Time { get; set; }
    string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}

public class TA : TableServiceEntity, Imust
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public class TB : TableServiceEntity, Imust
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public class TC : TableServiceEntity, Imust
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}    

public class _Table <T> : _Account where T : Imust 
{
}
```

Here the above 3 classes are implemented as Tables and its properties as its columns in my project. Imust interface is implemented in each class because in generic class i put an interface constraint. TableServiceEntity class contains the implementation for RowKey and PartitionKey.And this class is also inherited in all 3 entities.

**Problem** : Now i have to add a new table in my application. So for this i have to add a new class here which is

```
public class TD : TableServiceEntity
{

}
```

I do not want this class to implement the Imust interface because it does not contain these columns. But  i have to pass it as a parameter in generic class `_Table`.Because this new class has different columns but it perform same function which other 3 entities does. Now how will i add this new class while maintaining my existing structur ?

Please suggest me any better solution for this problem ?

**EDIT**

Yes i can put a constraint TableServiceEntity as a base class. But in generic class `_Table` there are few function which operate on `File` property  like

```
    public T AccessEntity(string Id = "0", string File = "0")
    {
        return (from e in ServiceContext.CreateQuery<T>(TableName)
                where e.RowKey == Id || e.File == File
                select e).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

If i removed this interface constraint then it shows an error that `T does not have a defination for File`.

Comment: Please, take a look at my answer. I believe that you could move those properties to a base class, review your inheritance structure and use the interface only to define methods.

Comment: @JCN  Follow up: if you got the answer you were looking for, don't forget to mark it as correct. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updated to reflect posters additional info:

You need to specify a new Interface:

```
public interface IMust2 {
    public string File {get;set;}
    public string Rowkey {get;set;

}
```

Modify IMust to inherit from IMust2

```
public interface IMust : IMust2 
{
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string Time {get;set;}
   public string PartitoinKey {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: You are using Rowkey and File in there so specify a new interface that includes only those properties

Comment: Isn't it what I suggested in separate answer I few minutes ago?

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this... the interface has no sense in your declaration as the more generic type for table is TableServiceEntity

```
public class _Table <T> : _Account where T : TableServiceEntity
{
}
```

Comment: You are assuming that all TableServiceEntities implement the properties used in _Table<T>

Answer (score 1):

Split the interface in two:

```
public interface Ibase

    string RowKey { get; set; }
    string PartitionKey { get; set; }
}

public interface Imust : Ibase
{
    string Name { get; set; }
    string File { get; set; }
    string Time { get; set; }
}

public class TA : TableServiceEntity, Imust
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public class TB : TableServiceEntity, Imust
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}

public class TC : TableServiceEntity, Imust
{
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string File { get; set; }
}    


public class _BaseTable <T> : _Account where T : Ibase 
{
}

public class _Table <T> : _BaseTable<T> where T : Imust 
{
}
```

And implement common functionality in `_BaseTable` and this specific to `Time`, `Name` and `File` in `_Table`.

It's even more intuitive after and edit you have made to your question. Thos methods in `_BaseTable` that rely on `File`, `Name` or `Time` can be marked abstract and overriden in `_Table`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have _Table be of `<TableServiceEntity>` type?   Obviously, you are breaking your interface, so you can't keep using it as the generic as not every class will be of that interface?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have 3 classes (TA, TB and TC) that are exactly the same. Why don't you have a single class, though?
2. For **behavior** (that is, methods), use a interface. For **structure** (that is, properties), use *inheritance* (like at `TableServiceEntity`).
3. Make TD inherit from the base class but do not implement the interface.
4. Change the restriction at `_Table` to be `where T : TableServiceEntity`

Regards

Comment: You are assuming that all TableServiceEntities implement the properties used in _Table<T>

Comment: @BonyT They may not implement it now, but they should, as it's an inheritance. That's why I started my answer by pointing out this little confusion with base class and interface

Comment: What if they can't - you cannot specify that every TableserviceEntity implement those properties without knowing a lot more about the overall design and schema.

Comment: @BonyT Indeed, but it's worth to review this class diagram. Having an interface to specify a few properties is very awkward

Comment: And how you define *similar items* if not by their properties? Similarity is all about the set of attributes, and it's all about inheritance.

Comment: Not at all - if they are the right properties. Interfaces are about grouping similar items - and is exactly the right approach in this scenario. (is what I meant to write) - abstract classes are far less useful, mostly because you can only ever have one.

Comment: Actually, interfaces are about code contract, not about similarity.

Comment: Chill =) Thanks for your attention, anyway

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14347/discussion-between-bonyt-and-andre-calil)